# HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Tags: java, servlets, filter

**filter**

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  

import javax.servlet.*;  

public class MyFilter implements Filter{  

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}  

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,  
    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {  

    PrintWriter out=resp.getWriter();  
    out.print("filter is invoked before");  

    chain.doFilter(req, resp);//sends request to next resource  

    out.print("filter is invoked after");  
    }  
    public void destroy() {}  
}
```

**servlet**

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  

import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.http.*;  

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {  
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  

        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

        out.print("<br>welcome to servlet<br>");  

    }  

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>  

<servlet>  
 <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>  
 <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
 <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>  
 <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  

<filter>  
 <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>  
 <filter-class>MyFilter</filter-class>  
</filter>  

<filter-mapping>  
 <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>  
 <url-pattern>/servlet1</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>  


</web-app>
```

**index.html**

```
     <a href="servlet1">click here</a>
```

error is :

**HTTP Status 404 - Not Found**

type Status report

messageNot Found

descriptionThe requested resource is not available.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0

I have given entire code plz help me find my error 
in am new to sevlet
question may sound dumb but plz help me

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

because your servlet is mapped to  `/HelloServlet` and your filter is trying to intercept  `servlet1` . since there is no servlet at `servlet1` , container says no resource found.

change your filter mapping to `/HelloServlet` and `<a href="/HelloServlet">click here</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
   <a href="/servlet1">click here</a>
```

With:

```
  <a href="/HelloServlet">click here</a>
```

Comment: filter mapping is changed to /* and <a href="/HelloServlet"">click here</a>

Comment: Why the apostrophes?

Comment: sorry <a href="/HelloServlet">click here</a>

Comment: i got output with above mentioned corrections thank u

Comment: it's working or not?

Comment: yes it working  it fine